# JS Tree - select_node not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jstree

I have a strange problem with JSTree and Ajax.

I generate my tree via an Ajax/PHP request which generates HTML (with UL,LI,A tags) using...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxTreeView.php?method=edit&partid='+partId,
    cache: false,
    success: function(tree)
    {
        $('#treeViewer').html(tree);
    }});
```

and activate JStree on the code using...

```
options = 
{
    "core": { animation: 120 },
    "themes": { theme: 'corral', dots: true },
    "types": 
    { 
        "types": 
        { 
            "parent": { "icon": { "image": "images/custom/Legend/node_select.png" } },
            "child": { "icon": { "image": "images/custom/Legend/node_select_child.png" } },
            "current": { "icon": { "image": "images/custom/Legend/node.png" } }
        }
    },
    "plugins": [ "html_data", "types", "themes", "ui", "contextmenu", "cookies" ],
    "ui": { "select_limit" : 1 },
    "cookies": { "save_selected" : false }
};

$("#tree").jstree(options);
```

I can't seem to get a node to select easily. I tried initially_select but this doesn't seem to work and also isn't ideal as I often want to programatically select node anyway.

I tried using...

```
$('#tree').jstree("select_node", '#ref565', true);
```

This works if I call the function via a hyperlink but doesn't work if I call it after I initalise JStree.

I see from adding an alert (all this happens in the Ajax Success routine)...

```
$('#treeViewer').html(tree);
$("#tree").jstree(options);
alert('test');
$('#tree').jstree("select_node", '#ref565', true);
```

... that the tree has not rendered before the alert kicks off.

I added a setTimeOut...

```
$('#treeViewer').html(tree);
$("#tree").jstree(options);
setTimeout(function() {selectNode(565);},1250);
$('#tree').jstree("select_node", '#ref565', true);
```

... this works.

I'm clearly being stupid. Am I using the wrong syntax? Why would I have to set a delay in order to select a node?

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to initially select certain nodes after the tree loads, you are supposed to use the [`initially_select`](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/ui) option of the [ui](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/ui) plugin.  You said you tried it, but I don't see it being used in the sample code you posted.  Are you sure you are supplying correct IDs?

To programmatically select nodes, you need to wait for the nodes you want to select to appear in the DOM first.  Rather than using a timeout call back, I'm guessing it is more correct to bind to the `loaded.jstree` event, which ought to be called after the tree has finished loading and all tree elements are in the DOM, and do your programmatic select in there.

Example code showing usage:

```
$(function () {

    $("#tree")
        .jstree({ 
            // List of active plugins
            "plugins" : [ 
                "ui"
            ],

            // UI & core - the nodes to initially select and open will be overwritten by the cookie plugin
            // the UI plugin - it handles selecting/deselecting/hovering nodes
            "ui" : {
                // this makes the node with ID node_4 selected onload
                "initially_select" : [ "#ref565" ]
            },
            // the core plugin - not many options here
            "core" : { 
                // just open those two nodes up
                // as this is an AJAX enabled tree, both will be downloaded from the server
                "initially_open" : [ "#ref565" ] 
            }
        })
        .bind("loaded.jstree", function (e, data) {
                  $('#tree').jstree("select_node", '#ref565', true); 
        }) 
});
```

Comment: This is just what I wanted but I see lots of code that starts with .bind after some googling. I'm being dumb, does this mean that I should write...

   $('#tree').jstree.bind("loaded.jstree", function(event, data) {
   $('#tree').jstree("select_node", '#ref565', true);
    });

If so, that isn't working for me.

Comment: I have updated my example showing how you would bind an event.  If something doesn't work due to coding error, please use the debugger to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm finding it much easier to understand these events now I realise they can be pre-bound upon instantiation of the tree. Great example, cheers :)

Comment: Great example, Bojin. Does `initially_open` load children via Ajax if the tree is lazy loaded?

Comment: Perfect answer and really useful for me :)